# Is it possible to access iPhone/iPad app files without jailbreak?

Tags: ios, xcode, resources

I mean not in-code access. For example I have installed app (through Testflight service) and I want to view/modify its resources.

I can download Library data from XCode organizer but not whole app. Maybe there is a way to download the app (to upload it back after modifications)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the .app of the application transfered to windows machine. In windows machine will be able to extract the contents inside the .app

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing an app, you can view the files in your application's sandbox. To do this in Xcode, open the Xcode organizer while the device is connected, select the "Devices" tab, open up the drop down button under your device name, select applications, and choose the app that you want to inspect the sandbox for. Then click the download button.

Hope this helps!

Comment: XCode Organizer shows only Library and Documents folders but not app package.